# Why is there a margin between my navbar and my banner?

Tags: html, css

For some reason, I set the margin for my banner and my  navbar to 0 and there is still a space between them. How can I fix this?

CSS

```
.body
{
margin-left: 200px;
margin-right: 200px;
margin-top: 50px;
margin-bottom: 100px;
}




#page{
    width: 1000px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}

.li_nav
{
float: left;
display:inline-block;
}

.nav 
{
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden; 
min-width: 1350px;  
}

a:link, a:visited 
{
display:inline-block;
width: 182.7px;
padding-top: 12px;
padding-right: 5px;
padding-bottom: 12px;
padding-left: 5px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #FFFFFF;
background-color: #990000;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: 'proxima-nova', sans-serif;
}

a:hover, a:active 
{
background-color: #B20000;
}

.body
{
height: 1350px;
}

.main_header
{
text-align: center;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
padding-left: 5px;
font-family: 'proxima-nova', sans-serif;
}

.main_body
{
padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.Team_Description 
{
font-size: 150%;
font-family: 'proxima-nova', sans-serif;
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index_style.css">
<title>Team 3774 Homepage</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="page">
<div class="Banner">
<img src="/Images/Banner.png" height="200" width="1350">
</div>

<div class="navbar">
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a class="li_nav" href="/Home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a class="li_nav" href="/Team Bio">Team Bio</a></li>
  <li><a class="li_nav" href="/Our Robot">Our Robot</a></li>
  <li><a class="li_nav" href="/Our Coach">Our Coach</a></li>
  <li><a class="li_nav" href="/Gallery">Gallery</a></li>
  <li><a class="li_nav" href="/Outreach">Outreach</a></li>
  <li><a class="li_nav" href="/Youtube">Youtube</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

<div class="body">
<h1 class="main_header">Welcome to Robotics Team 3774!</h1>
<div class="main_body">
<p class="Team_Description">Hive Voltage 3774 is the Senior 
(and Junior) 
Engineering Team at Bayonne High School. The team 
is a part of the Senior Engineering class available 
at Bayonne High School. This team has the most experienced
 students for FTC. Many of them are highly capable students 
 who had done various stem activities. We plan on learning 
 several aspects of engineering this season but we also intend to
 have fun.
 Our main goal however is to grow as a team. We plan to grow 
 as individuals and to collaborate as a unit or a team.
 Also, we plan to expose our community to the wonderful 
 applications of robotics, and to excel in many parts of real
 engineering and real world applications. Hence we are, 
 HIVE VOLTAGE 3774. #Hivevoltage #Gobees</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am building the site for my high school robotics team. The site is robotichive3774.com

Comment: the default value of vertical-align is baseline. Change it to top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the default vertical alignment of an inline element (in your case the image in the banner) is baseline and you want top:

```
.Banner img {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2skrfjgd/1)**

Comment: Why not just set the image to display as `block` instead?

Comment: @disinfor - Why change the display property over the vertical alignment?

Comment: Good call. I was honestly curious, hopefully it didn't come off as challenging your correct answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot.... I am completely new to CSS and HTML so I am unaware of the elements' natural tendencies.

Comment: @user3362546 here are some resources for you to help you wrap your head around them:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elemente

Answer (score 0):

Try `display:flex;` at the `.Banner` style.

http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/morpfLqh/1/

Displays an element as an block-level flex container. New in CSS3

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the height on your image:

```
<img src="/Images/Banner.png" height="200" width="1350">
```